# Limit `nmcli dev wifi` to display one entry per unique SSID

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

When I use the graphical interface to NetworkManager (via the tray icon), it displays around 10
SSIDs (for my current location). However, when I use `nmcli dev wifi` it
returns around 55 entries. The reason is that the same SSID is
returned multiple times with different signal strength (and sometimes even
different transfer rate). Most of the duplicate SSIDs have distinct
channels/bands, but some have the same.

Sample output

```
IN-USE  SSID               MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
        G4_9647            Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   84      ▂▄▆█  WPA2        
        Telekom            Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  --          
        Airport-Frankfurt  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  --          
        FRAWiSe            Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X 
        FRAWiSe            Infra  48    405 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA2 802.1X 
        Airport-Frankfurt  Infra  48    405 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  --          
        Ca81pVb5jKTw       Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA2        
        Telekom            Infra  48    405 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  --          
        Airport-Frankfurt  Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  57      ▂▄▆_  --          
        Telekom            Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  --          
        FRAWiSe            Infra  36    270 Mbit/s  55      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X 
        Ca81pVb5jKTw       Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        AndroidAP 3        Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   50      ▂▄__  WPA2        
        FRAWiSe            Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2 802.1X
```

The following commands also lists around 55 connections

```
sudo iwlist wlp4s0 scan | grep ESSID
```

```
sudo iw dev wlp4s0 scan | grep SSID
```

How can I achieve the same result from using `nmcli` as with the NetworkManager
GUI and limit the results to one entry per unique SSID? I would like to achieve
this without knowing which channel/band the SSIDs are on (in which case I could
just use grep). For example, returning just the entry with the channel/band that has the highest signal strength.

Answer (score 1):

```
nmcli dev wifi | awk -F'  +' '{ if (!seen[$2]++) print}'
```

The awk script works as follows:

- -F'  +' - Separator is two or more spaces
- If the 2nd column (SSID) has not been seen previously then print. Then add 1 to that value so that next time it's not printed

Comment: Great, thank you! The only downside is that the colorized text output is not retained after piping through `awk`. Any idea how to fix that? Seems like it's not just passed as ANSI color codes